# points separation and dimensions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, banach-algebras

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a sub-algebra of $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

If $\mathcal{A}$ separates points in $[0,1]$, does it follow $\dim\mathcal{A}=\infty$?

Comment: Try using Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Comment: If you can detail as an answer, I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\mathcal{A}$ contains the constant functions (otherwise, just add them to $\mathcal{A}$, it will increase the dimension by $1$). Hence, $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies the conditions of Stone-Weierstrass theorem, and so is dense in $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Now if $\dim\mathcal{A}<\infty$, it is close in $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ (every finitely dimensional subspace of a normed space is closed), and since it is also dense, we get that $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, which clearly contradicts to  $\dim\mathcal{A}<\infty$.

Comment: Adding constants may increase the dimension infinitely (the quotient can have an infinite dimension).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Why? $\mathcal{A}$ is already an **algebra** over the reals, so by adding constants we actually add them to the elements

Comment: Let $\ A\ $ be an algebra of functions which vanish on the Cantor set. Then add constant functions and see what happens.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński We get the algebra of functions which are constants when restricted to the Cantor set.

Comment: ( Indeed, for $\ f\ g\ \in A\ $ arbitrary, and $\ c\ d\ $ constant, we get $\ (f+c)\cdot(g+d)\ =\ f\!\cdot\! g + d\!\cdot\!f + c\!\cdot\!g + c\!\cdot\!d,\ $, i.e. something from $\ A\ $ plus a constant. )

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński Yes, this is exactly what I meant =)

Answer (score 4):

While the above answer completely answered the OP's question, there is an elementary approach, which actually gives a little bit more: Let $f$ be a non-constant, continuous function on $[0,1]$. Then the set $\{f, f^2, f^3, \ldots\}$ (here $f^n$ is the $n$th power of $f$), as a subset of $C([0,1])$, is linear independent. Indeed, if not, then $P(f)=0$ on $[0,1]$ for some non-zero polynomial $P$. This would imply that the set $f([0,1])$ is contained in the set of all roots of $P$, a finite set. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: That is very nice.